# Does the time.sleep() method not make my widget come up?

Tags: python, time, tkinter

I'm trying to make a button, that when you press the button "Send", it will show for 2 seconds the words "Your message has been sent".
When I start the program, I press "Send", but it doesn't show anything. I think its something to do with the "time.sleep()" method. Can someone tell me whats wrong here?

```
class Application(Frame):
def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    self.lbl1=Label(self, text="Write your message:")
    self.lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    self.entry=Entry(self)
    self.entry.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=3, sticky=W)

    self.bttn=Button(self, text="Send", command=self.send)
    self.bttn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)


def send(self):
    self.lbl2=Label(self, text="Your message has been sent")
    self.lbl2.grid(row=2, column=0,  columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    self.disappear()

def disappear(self):
    start=time.time()
    time.sleep(2)
    self.lbl2.grid_remove()
```

Comment: See my comment on your previous question: "Actually it's probably not advisable to use sleep at all in a Tkinter program, since it temporarily halts the mainloop and causes the application to become totally unresponsive. If you want an event to occur after a certain amount of time, consider using root.after instead."

Comment: I saw your comment, thanks but can you explain how the after method works?

Comment: `sleep` does exactly what it says: it makes your program -- your _whole_ program -- go to sleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a Tkinter app? You'd probably be better off using something like

```
root.after(2000, disappear)
```

To invoke your disappear function after 2 seconds.

Comment: Great! Did you need to change your disappear method at all?

Comment: Also, feel free to accept this answer if it has helped :), thanks!